# Custom order by string parameter in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I had an HQL query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User as user where user.joined!=null order by user.joined desc");
```

How do I set a variable User property as the sort order for my query? My solution:

```
String order = "user.joined";
Query query = session.createQuery("from User as user where user.joined!=null order by :order desc").setString("order", order);
```

does not give an ordered query result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [criteria query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html).

```
List<User> users = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("joined"))
    .addOrder(Order.desc(order))
    .list();
```

---

Or, using HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User as user where user.joined!=null order by user." + order + " desc");
```

Comment: Hm, too bad SQL-Injection is possible.

Comment: @Grim only if `order` is a string, with no validation, passed in from the caller. Which is probably a bad idea, regardless 

Comment: I think it is not critical. I mean, what can happen? You could inject a Union statement. Maybe some performance problems (I do not mean the recompile into sql, I mean performance taking selections). But yea, validation might help. :D

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, when you use this method call:

```
[Hibernate Query object].setString("order", order)
```

You are trying to bind a column name as a parameter, which is not possible.

What is a parameter (for this concern) follows the SQL parameters definition, wich is also the parameter definition used in [JDBC API PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

To dynamically build a query (besides it's parameters) there are other solutions like the ones pointed by Matt Ball. You could also see [Using a prepared statement and variable bind Order By in Java with JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430208/using-a-prepared-statement-and-variable-bind-order-by-in-java-with-jdbc-driver).