# Checking if values is in database with springboot - exactly once called

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I would like to check if `columnName` is in table `T` in database. I am using spring boot and mybatis. 
This checking should be done exactly once, to not do overhead in network transfer and time.

**Why ?**
In my `mybatis SQL query` I have `SELECT * FROM T .. ORDER BY ${columnName}`. You know that it is prone to SQL Injection.  So I must check if `columnName` is proper column name in table.

**Approach 1**
Hard Code in app columns of table `T`.
**Approach 2**

```
List <String> columnNames;
@PostConstruct
void initColumnNames() {
   columnNames = mapper.getColumnNames();
}
```

**Approach 3**
in DAO (or mayby validation class) ?:

```
void someDaoMethod(String columnName) {
   if (columnNames == null) { //using approach 2 this if is unneccessary
      columnNames = mapper.getColumnNames();
   }
   //check if columName is allowed (= is in columnNames)
}
```

Can you help me solve this problem ? What approach should I choose ?

Comment: iBatis uses prepared statements, so as long as your using the # notation, the queries will be safe from sql injection.

Comment: @Gregg you are wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430208/using-a-prepared-statement-and-variable-bind-order-by-in-java-with-jdbc-driver

Comment: @HaskellFun I'm okay with being wrong, but unsure how that post suggests that. Also, seems there might be nicer ways to tell someone they are wrong.

Comment: @Gregg, hold your horses. My English is too weak to understand that `you are wrong` is offensive. Direct translation to my mother tongue is ok.  I am intrested in how this problem (stated by OP) is solved.

Comment: @HaskellFun Understood. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using??

Comment: @Pau SQL Server 2012